# Tag synonym request: [xhr] -> [xmlhttprequest]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Currently, 282 questions are tagged [xhr](/questions/tagged/xhr), which should be marked a synonym of [xmlhttprequest](/questions/tagged/xmlhttprequest).

The synonym is obviously correct. However, due the [**low volume**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhr/topusers) of [xhr](/questions/tagged/xhr) questions, the synonym voting is stuck at +1. Could anyone mark [xhr](/questions/tagged/xhr) as a synonym of [xmlhttprequest](/questions/tagged/xmlhttprequest)?

Comment: +1 I've also upvoted the synonym request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Done](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlhttprequest/synonyms).

Comment: Thanks, the shortcut is really useful :)